# Animate only div of clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the text of div if paragraph extend a specific height and by clicking a button that height changes to full but by clicking the button all divs are affected I want to animate only parent div of that button not just line in this case where only first div that extends that height is affected by button click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var text = $('.description'),
     btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
       h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 120) {
 btn.addClass('less');
 btn.css('display', 'block');
}

 $(".emp-bio .btn-overflow").click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
      $(this).removeClass('less');
      $(this).addClass('more');
      $(this).text('Show less');

      text.animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      $(this).addClass('less');
      $(this).removeClass('more');
      $(this).text('Show more');
      text.animate({'height': '120px'});
  }  
});


});
```

```css
.description {
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="emp-bio">
<div class="description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<a class="btn-overflow" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div class="emp-bio">
<div class="text-overflow">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<a class="btn-overflow" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

hopefully my snippet can help you in some way.

have a nice day,,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var text = $('.description'),
     btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
       h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 120) {
 btn.addClass('less');
 btn.css('display', 'block');
}

 $(".emp-bio .btn-overflow").click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
      $(this).removeClass('less');
      $(this).addClass('more');
      $(this).text('Show less');

      //use siblings to access .description in same level.
      $(this).siblings( ".description" ).animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      $(this).addClass('less');
      $(this).removeClass('more');
      $(this).text('Show more');

      //use siblings to access .description in same level.
      $(this).siblings( ".description" ).animate({'height': '120px'});
  }  
});


});
```

```css
.description {
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="emp-bio">
<div class="description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<a class="btn-overflow" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div class="emp-bio">
<div class="description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<a class="btn-overflow" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```