# How to select element in jQuery by function id parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to delete an Item in my to do list App

```
deletItem: function(id) {
        $(id).remove();
        console.log(id);
    },
```

Here is the function who calls deletItem

```
function delItem(event) {
    var itemID, splitID, type, ID;
    itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    splitID = itemID.split("-");
    type = splitID[0];
    ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);

    budgetCtrl.delItem(type, ID);
    UICtrl.deletItem(itemID);
    updatBudget();
    console.log(itemID);
}
```

But, the Item is calculating bt not getting deleted from UI only.
Please help.

Comment: can you please provide more codes? so other contributor like me, can reproduce the problem.. checkout this question as example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697085/animate-only-div-of-clicked-button)

Comment: Missing the `'#'` prefix for id selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
deletItem: function(id) {
    $('#' + id).remove();
    console.log(id);
},
```

What you tried earlier won't work because when using jQuery, you must have a '#' or '.' in front of the class or id. For example, lets say the id was "deleteThis"
Then, you would be basically doing:

```
$('deleteThis').remove();
```

You should be doing

```
$('#deleteThis').remmove();
```